# Async call on App Delegate

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous, alamofire

I'm using Alamofire to configure my WebService classes in Swift. But now every time the app back from background, I need to make an Request before the root view controller gets loaded.

So, here is an sample code of my WS call.

```
WS.chooseInstance(instanceiD, accessToken: self.accessToken, handler: {
   (urlRequest, urlResponse, result, error) in

   if urlResponse?.statusCode == 200 {
     self.requestAllStages()
    }
})
```

The issue: All the data of my app is gonna be on the web, so, I make requests with Alamofire. But i need to get the data before the view render it self, but when I try to make the request on awakeFromNib or ViewDidLoad, it don't wait for the request to end, and keep going with the lifecycle. I need a way to make the view wait for the request and then keep going, but I'm totaly lost hehe –  user3658007 1 hour ago

Thanks!

Comment: What's your question? Update your "question" with an actual question or discussion of your issue.

Comment: The issue: All the data of my app is gonna be on the web, so, I make requests with Alamofire. But i need to get the data before the view render it self, but when I try to make the request on awakeFromNib or ViewDidLoad, it don't wait for the request to end, and keep going with the lifecycle. I need a way to make the view wait for the request and then keep going, but I'm totaly lost hehe

Comment: Please move your "The Issue" comment to the question so people don't have to read all comments to understand what is the problem. That being said, you should not make synchronous long running web service calls in functions like viewDidLoad or awakeFromNib. Your app will stall. This might be a good reason for AppStore to reject your app.

Comment: Thanks! So , i gonna search about NSoperations, maybe is a solution

Comment: What do you expect to happen if the device is not connected to the Internet and the user tries to use your app?

Comment: He cannot use the app offline,  cause its Just an complement app for a web system.

Comment: Só,  everytime he closes the app,  it goes to login screen,  Just in one case it goes to other screen,  and if there is no Internet connection it will shows a message